# How do I offset an openGL object while still keeping the projection like I'm looking straight at it?

Tags: opengl, matrix, perspective

My brain has melted as I've spent forever on this problem.

I need to offset a cube from the origin by two in both the x and y direction however keep the one point perspective like I'm looking straight at it.

Everytime I translate the cube it is acting as if the projection is coming from the origin.

I cant figure out how to do it.

```
//this is here to draw a graph  
glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);  
glLoadIdentity();  
glOrtho(-10,10,-10,10,-10,10);  
glBegin(GL_LINES);  
glVertex3f(-10, 0,0);  
glVertex3f(10, 0 ,0);  
glVertex3f(0, -10,0);  
glVertex3f(0, 10 ,0);  
glEnd();  



glPushMatrix();  
glLoadIdentity();  
glFrustum(-2.0, 2.0, -2.0, 2.0, 5, 100);

gluLookAt( 0,0,-6,
       0, 0, 0,
       0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glutWireCube (.5);

glPopMatrix();

glFlush();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using gluLookAt on the projection matrix. This is wrong, gluLookAt is to be applied on the modelview matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You're leaving `GL_PROJECTION` mode active while you do this. At least if I understand what you're asking for, you want to use `GL_PROJECTION` while you set up your viewport (e.g., with `glOrtho`), but for the actual drawing, you want to work in `GL_MODELVIEW` mode.

Comment: The matrix mode is not relevant to drawing calls. However the OP uses gluLookAt on the projection matrix, which is wrong. gluLookAt is to be used on the modelview matrix.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I found a solution to my problem using multiple viewports.  I create my primary viewport then a smaller one in the bottom left corner. Thanks to yalls comments now my glulookat is affecting my modelview matrix.